# Why is bash swallowing characters

Tags: bash, stdin

I have the following code in a bash script:

```
ssh_management
if [[ "$PROMPT_SSH" == "true" ]]; then
  read -p "Generate and Install SSH keys? [y/n]" -n 1 -r
  echo ""
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    generate_container_ssh
    install_ssh_keys
    check_ssh_state
  else
    echo "Skipping SSH key install"
  fi
fi
install_docker
```

But the script errors with:

```
Skipping container SSH key install
bash: line 102: nstall_docker: command not found
```

It appears that the read command is somehow swalling the first character on `install_docker`

Not sure why this is happening or how it fix it.

Comment: `It appears that the read command` ok, then remove the `read` and try again. `why this is happening` Which line is line 102? IS the file being modified while running? Is there no `nstall_docker` in the file? Are there unprintable characters in the file?

Comment: Does your file perhaps have Windows style CRLF line endings when you're using an OS that expects LF?

Comment: @KamilCuk Removing the read line fixes the problem (this is how I knew it was the read command). Line 102 is the 'install_docker' function.

Comment: @Shawn I'm developing on Windows, but vscode is saying line endings are LF. I'm testing this script on both WSL and a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Seems something was messing up my STDIN.

```
read -p "Generate and Install SSH keys? [y/n]" -n 1 -r < /dev/tty
```

Fixes the problem.